# NSTimer firing instantly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I'm trying to develop a game and running into a small issue with NSTimer, once a sprite appear it has a certain amount on time in my scene before fading out.

```
double CALC_TIME = 5;
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:CALC_TIME target:self selector:@selector(hideSprite) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

I want hideSprite to be called after 5 seconds, but instead it's called instantly(Or near instant).

**A possible solution:**
I know I could do this by setting the timer to repeat, and having a bool firstCall that is set first time and then the next interval the fading is done, the timer is invalidated but I don't think this is good practice

Like this:

```
bool firstCall = false;
-(void)hideSprite{
        if(!firstCall){
        firstCall = true
    }else{
        //fade out sprite
        //Invalidate NSTimer
        //firstCall = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This should work. Something else is wrong-- are you sure that `hideSprite` is not being called by any other code? Like some test code still left in immediately after the timer is set up?

Comment: Nope, I've just checked there, the method is only called from one place, 

I added an NSLog, one just after I initialize the method, and one in the method as it's called.

Keeps the output:



_2011-12-19 21:43:11.547 Squish Em[14144:10a03] Timer Called
2011-12-19 21:43:11.562 Squish Em[14144:10a03] Called Timer
2011-12-19 21:43:16.582 Squish Em[14144:10a03] Timer Called
2011-12-19 21:43:16.596 Squish Em[14144:10a03] Called Timer_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect something else is calling `hideSprite`. The code you have written *will* cause the timer to wait for five seconds before calling the selector `hideSprite`.

Provide a different selector (write a new test method which just does an `NSLog`) to the timer and see what happens. This will tell you a) whether the timer is indeed immediately firing and b) if something else is calling `hideSprite`.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:CALC_TIME target:self selector:@selector(testTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void) testTimer { NSLog(@"Timer - and only the timer - called me."); }
-(void) hideSprite {
    NSLog(@"I definitely wasn't called by the timer.");
}
```

Comment: I did this, and weirdly enough it started calling this method five seconds after, I changed it back and now it's running correctly, but I'm not sure why... Thanks for your help though, time to look at my code and see what's going on!

Comment: Ah, gremlins. They're real, you know :)

Answer (score 1):

Quite often it's easier to just use something like

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 0 delay: 5 options:0 animations: nil completion:
^{
  // fade sprite
}];
```

(not sure if `animations` can be nil, but you get the idea).

Comment: Although it's a smart way to resolve the problem, it's not correct to use animations just to trigger a method with a certain delay.

Answer (score 0):

Consider initializing your timer using the `initWithFireDate:interval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats` method.  Here is a more detailed look at [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html).

Comment: Can you explain why you think this would be helpful? Using this method would mean calculating a fire date instead of just using a time interval, and also create more concern about the memory management of the timer.